# Bitbucket pushing tags when issue key linking is turned on fails

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket

I am able to make commits and push them to the server successfully.  However when I create a tag and try to push it I get these messages.  I've searched Bitbucket docs and found nothing.  I searched to see if I can add a commit message to a tag but that does not seem possible or necessary...

To turn on issue linking I selected the on/off slider in the repository settings/links and don't seem to have any other ability to change things.

```
$ git push origin --tags
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 1.80 KiB | 922.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: You have 3 commit messages that are missing valid issue keys:
remote: 
remote:   13cdaac: v1.4.0
remote:   f84bab9: v1.3.0
remote:   a6a1dc1: v1.2.1
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
To https://bitbucket.org/xxx/server.git
 ! [remote rejected] p1.9 -> p1.9 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] v1.2.1 -> v1.2.1 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] v1.3.0 -> v1.3.0 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] v1.4.0 -> v1.4.0 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx/server.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK had an afterthought after putting this question together.  Some items that had been tagged locally before adding the "issue key" linking in the repository.  So I deleted the keys that existed before and then pushed.  It worked for newly created tags.